# Which jquery reference am i missing

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a razor cshtml view that uses jquery. I get following error during certain user action.

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property
>   'unobtrusiveValidationAttributes': object is null or undefined

When error happen, debugger breaks at 
MVCx.GetEditorByElement(b).unobtrusiveValidationAttributes[c+ this]});
from following line of code

```
 function(b,i){var d=a(b),f=d.parents("form")[0],c,e,g;if(!f)return;c=a(f).data("unobtrusiveValidation");c.options.rules[b.name]=e={};c.options.messages[b.name]=g={};a.each(this.adapters,function(){var c="data-val-"+this.name,i=MVCx.GetEditorByElement(b).unobtrusiveValidationAttributes[c],h={};if(i!==undefined){c+="-";a.each(this.params,function(){h[this]=MVCx.GetEditorByElement(b).unobtrusiveValidationAttributes[c + this]});this.adapt({element:b,form:f,message:i,params:h,rules:e,messages:g})}});jQuery.extend(e,{__dummy__:true});!i&&c.attachValidation()}
```

My theory is that error is caused because I may not have referece to certain JQuery file (missing   some  `<script src="@Url.Content("~/ApplicationScripts/JQuery/jquery-1.4.4.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>.`

Assuming its casued by missing jquery reference, one way of solving it is by adding all jquery references (obviously tedious). I wonder if there is better way of finding which jquery reference is actually needed.

**UPDATE**
This is how my references are setup right now

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/ApplicationScripts/JQuery/jquery-1.4.4.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/ApplicationScripts/JQuery/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/ApplicationScripts/JQuery/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/ApplicationScripts/JQuery/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Could you show your list of javascript references?

Comment: updated question for my list of references. I wonder if the order of these files matters?

Comment: The error is occuring when these libs are loaded or is there code being run? If there is code being run, is it run after document ready or when it compiles? Can we see that too?

Comment: The order of the files certainly matters but I think you've got it right here. validate.unobtrusive almost certainly needs to come after the others. Also, have you tried a more recent version of jquery? 1.4.4 is a bit old; perhaps one of these libs needs a newer version?

Comment: `jquery`, `jquery.validate`, and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive` should be all you need. You might be barking up the wrong tree... I would try debugging using the unminified files. Also, as Kato suggests, try updating all those libraries with more recent versions.

Comment: @Kato: Error happens when code is been run, after document ready. Can yuo please elaborate what should I post that will help understand what is going on. This code is part of big project, I am not sure what should I post so that you see what's going on.

Comment: I will try your suggestions to see if this help solve problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC 3 comes with `jquery-1.5.1.js`. You seem to be using `jquery-1.4.4.min.js`. I am not sure that the jquery.validate plugin and the other unobtrusive scripts are compatible with this version of jQuery. Try using the default scripts that are provided when creating a new application.

Comment: I can certainly try that. But my basic question is really how to findout which reference am I missing. In a C# project, if your API needs a certain assembly, you can just go to msdn, search for that API and that will tell you which assembly you need for reference. Is there any such mechansim in JQuery?

Comment: @imak, no, there isn't such mechanism for javascript.

Comment: Thanks for your tip. Upgrading juqery to 1.5.1 solved my issue